# Restar a la fecha actual un numero de horas en moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Estoy utilizando la librería moment.js, en nodejs y javascript y necesito en dos campos "Fecha_Inicio" y "Fecha_Fin" que la fecha_inicio siempre sea 2 horas antes a la fecha actual, pero en punto y la fecha_fin será una hora antes a la actual pero en punto.

Pongo un ejemplo:

```
Fecha_Actual: 2019-02-11T14:36
Fecha_Inicio: 2019-02-11T12:00
Fecha_Fin:    2019-02-11T13:00
```

En estos momentos recojo la información de tal manera:

```
var fechaInicio = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm');
```

Estoy probado alguna opciones de la documentación de este estilo como mencionan (cambiando el day por hour pero no funciona como necesito)

```
moment().day(-7); // last Sunday (0 - 7)
```

Toda ayuda es buena.

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MomentJS tiene una función **[subtract](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/)** que se encarga de realizar restas de segundos, horas, dias, etc.

Ahora bien, como tu deseas setear las horas y restar los minutos - si es que existen - debes realizar algo como esto

```js
const getTime = () => {
  const date = moment().subtract(2, 'hours')
  const minute = date.minutes()
  
  alert(date.subtract(minute, 'minutes').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm'))
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getTime()">Obtener fecha</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

En resumen, obtenemos la fecha actual y le restamos dos horas dejando el formato que trae momentjs por defecto, *ya que si tratas de restar los minutos a una fecha con un formato distinto no funciona*. Finalmente, una vez que realizas las restas necesarias puedes dar el `format` que desees a tu fecha.

Nos comentas que tal te va :)

Comment: Gracias Paulo, esto era lo que necesitaba. Un saludo.